# Tomcat equivalent for IBM security provider com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, security

I have to migrate application for IBM Websphere to Tomcat and in the java, there is a code that uses IBM Security Provider.

```
Security.addProvider(new com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE())
```

This may be a straight forward question but I want to know what to use instead of above when I migrate the app to run in tomcat. Any specific Java Security Provider implementation or should I have to write one by myself?

Comment: Depending on you JDK version you run Tomcat on there are default [JCE previders available to you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html). Is there anything special in the IBM provider you need?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.6.I dont need IBM Provider anymore,coz previously the application was hosted in websphere, now its migrated to tomcat.so,above addProvider() has to be changed right?sorry for my low knowledge on the matter,I am new to the concept.

Comment: Showing us only one line of code is rather sparse, but I would eliminate that line, completely and expect it to work anyway.